# Open Bacula Backup Files

Tags: bacula

Is it possible to open backup files made by Bacula Backup with tools like 7zip or WinRAR so that I can browse the backups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly, but you can use "bls" and "bextract" programs from Bacula Volume Utility Tools. You can read more here:

http://www.bacula.org/5.0.x-manuals/en/utility/utility/index.html